# Difference between Magento CE and Magento EE

Tags: magento

I have an extension that works perfectly in Magento CE 1.9.2.1 and as well as EE 1.1.2

How can I test the extension for compatibility for v 1.1.4.x of Magento EE?

Answer (score 0):

There is no a perfect check to understand if it works with any Magento version. You should test it or ask to the developer, but the answer is: there is no way unless test it.